# Is this a thread safe code?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, multithreading, forms

i have three functions in a module that several threads would be using. all of the functions access local variable except the main doWork sub.

```
    Sub DoWork(byval i as integer)

synclock (ListTasks)
dim strItem  as string =ListTasks(CInt(i)).ToString
end SyncLock

dim strHtml as string = GetHtml(strItem )
dim strParsed as string = ParseHtml(strHtml)
dim strResult as string = Report(strParsed )
End sub

Function GetHtml(byval url as string) as string
'code to get website
ens sub

Function ParseHtml(Byval html as string) as string
'code to parse HtmlString
end function

Function Report(Byval html as string) as string
'do the work
end function
```

Is this a thread safe code, so that no thread will overwrite data?

Comment: Where else is `ListTasks` used in your code?  That code is important, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If each function are all using local variables (within the functions, each function is stateless and do not access any shared resources) and all the parameters are passed by value, so that its a separate copy in the stack ( not a reference to another object), it should be threadsafe and you really do not need any locking.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like pretty much everything you're using is a local variable.  Your also passing variables by value, not by reference, which helps for thread safety.  So you appear to be pretty safe!  Just make sure the one lock your using doesn't get you into a race condition.